# Cauchy problem for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Cauchy problem $$y z_x-xz_y=0$$
and $ x_0(s)=cos (s),y_0(s)=sin(s),z_0(s)=1,s>0$

I use Lagrange's method

$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-x}=\frac{dz}{0}$$
From 1st and 2nd 
$x^2+y^2=c_1$ and from last relation $z=c_2$
So solution is of the type $z = f(x^2+y^2)$
By initial condition

$$1=f(cos^2s+sin^2s) \implies 1 = f(1) $$  so  what i concluded from this about the solution to the problem ?  Please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly found the general solution is 
$$z(x,y)=f(x^2+y^2)$$
and the condition is $$f(1)=1$$
Thus any function $f(X)$ which is equal to $1$ when the argument is equal to $1$ is convenient.

They are an infinity of functions such as $f(1)=1$ . Thus the specified condition is not sufficient to determine a unique solution. With the actual wording the problem has an infinity of solutions.

For examples :

With $f(X)=X^n$ then $z=(x^2+y^2)^n$ is solution.

With $f(X)=e^{X-1}$ then $z=e^{x^2+y^2-1}$ is solution.

With $f(X)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} X)$ then $z=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} (x^2+y^2))$ is solution.

Etc.

Comment: Thankyou very much I got your point 
One more question : is there are condition  which quickly tell that Cauchy problem has unique solution, no solution, or infinitely many solution without solving  Cauchy problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou very much I got your point 
One more question : is there are condition  which quickly tell that Cauchy problem has unique solution, no solution, or infinitely many solution without solving  Cauchy problem ?